# Empty string passed to getElementById -- Responsive Filemanager

Tags: tinymce-plugins

We are using the ResponsiveFilemanager with TinyMCE, inside SocialEngine 4.

The plugin worked fine until we moved to a new server. We have not changed the configuration at all, but now the plugin does not work -- when we click on the image, nothing in happens. In Firefox, the message

Empty string passed to getElementById() (plugins.js:1:0)

... is displayed in the debugger.

I'm really not sure what other information it would best to include here, since we haven't changed any of the code while moving. But for completion, the old set up was standard LAMP, the new set up is Nginx+FPM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consultation with the original developer, we found that it was caused by the "crossdomain" argument passed to the plugin which for us had been set to true in the SocialEngine config. We editted line 75 of the file application/libraries/Engine/View/Helper/TinyMce.php and set 'filemanager_crossdomain'=> false, then the plugin started to work again.